# How to find particular json document from couchdb

Tags: couchdb, cloudant, couchdb-futon

How to find particular json document details from couchdb

For ex : Database name : employee_mgmt, in that database contains 50 json documents. So i want to find particular employee json documents ( Find by employee id ).

Comment: Was the answer helpful? If, then mark as answer, if not, why?

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, please accept it.  If the answer didn't help, you can add a comment to the answer to say why.  If you don't accept answers that worked for you, people will be reluctant to answer your future questions.

Comment: You may want to read the [stackoverflow help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a qood question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see why your question has been marked down.

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB does in it self not provide you with collections/buckets, hence all your documents are peers. It's up to you to provide meta-data e.g. by having a property `$doctype` with a value representing what kind of document it is. This is useful if you are writing `maps` and e.g. want to create a view (secondary index) returning something applicable only to employees.

Know, if you just want to query by `_id` you don't need the above. Just do a simple `GET` with an `URI` as: `http://host:port/databasename/documentid`

More information: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/document/common.html#get--db-docid

If you want to get a batch of documents matching many `_id` use the builtin index `_all_docs` http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/database/bulk-api.html#post--db-_all_docs